# RoR ActiveRecord save method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im new to Rails, im trying to execute the save method within an ActionController's Create method multiple times to insert multiple values

```
def create

  @pin = Pin.new(params[:pin])
  i = 1

  while i < 10
    if @pin.save
    end
  end

  redirect_to @pin

end
```

This works but only inserts one record
there's no Contraints that enforces uniqueness of Records in my Database.
Please how do i correct this?

Comment: BTW you have an endless loop in here, since you never increment i within the loop.

Comment: Opps, Omitted what while reproducing the code here, that's not ommited in the original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One AR objects maps to one row. You need to create new object for each row you want added.

Something like that:

```
10.times do
  pin = Pin.new(params[:pin])
  pin.save
end
```

or

```
10.times do 
  Pin.create(params[:pin]
end
```

`create` method creates an AR object and saves it in the database.
However, you cannot redirect to 10 objects.

Answer (score 0):

you should extend your resource with create_multiple method and send params as array, see the details [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?autoplay=true)